# How do I get the current year in the footer?

Tags: theming

I want to put a copyright notice in the footer of my posts, and I want the year always to be current.  I've tried adding

```
<?php echo date("Y"); ?>
```

to the Footer, but the actual code shows up; it doesn't get parsed as PHP.

How do I get the footer to display the current year?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That happens because you are creating a custom block, but you didn't select PHP code as input format.

In Drupal 7, you need to first enable the PHP module (php.module); in Drupal 6, you need to first enable the input format on admin/settings/filters. Once you have done that, you will be able to choose PHP code as input format, and write PHP code between `<?php` `?>` tags; the code will be executed, and the output will be the content of the block.

Answer (score 2):

Disable rich-text format and rewrite it correctly.
In html format is symbols like < or " are actually parsed as `&lt ;`  and `& quot ;`.
so rewrite it to the correct PHP code.